# Can you export drop shadows, etc, to PSD and maintain transparency?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, shadows

I'm really new to Adobe Illustrator and I've looked around here and while some posts show that it's possible, I'm not able to replicate what they're doing.

I have a logo in Ai that I would like to export to PSD, but when I do, the drop shadows are replaced by like a white background surrounding the logo instead of shadows. I've tried to just cmd + a to select all from Ai and paste into Ps, but then it pastes everything except for the shadows and other glowing effects.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just simply not supported?

Comment: Have you tried just opening (not converting or exporting) the Illustrator file in Photoshop?  I just tried it with an illustrator file I have with a drop shadow and it works fine.

Comment: Lurking around this site enough I am ready to admit that Photoshop may make better shadows than illustrator. If it's possible to turn off or delete the shadow in illustrator (look in the appearances panel) then just make new shadows in Photoshop. PS can open AI files and vice versa, you should try that first. When I export transparent .PNGs the shadows are preserved correctly.

Comment: @magerber just tried to open my Ai file in Photoshop and it did the same thing. Where the shadows (outer shadows, drop shadows, etc.) would go, it's white instead. No shadows whatsoever.

Comment: Agreed @Webster that's about the only way I can get things rolling, is to completely get rid of shadows and then re-do it all in Photoshop. Kind of sucks though :( Was hoping to have a base AI logo for everything, and I guess I still can, just not when I export it.

Comment: Are you getting any transparency from your illustrator file at all?  Try exporting the Illustrator file to a image type that supports transparency (.png or .tif), and then open that file in Photoshop.  If that file also doesn't show the drop shadow, then it is likely something funky about how you created the drop shadow.

Comment: @magerber I guess if I open it as PNG it works, but then I can't edit layers since it just opens it as an image. Guess there's not a way to do that properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like the following:

[image]

OR

If you do not want to have editing capability including layers then it can be done easily by the following:

1. In Illustrator save the file as a PNG format from the menu 'File >
   Save for Web'.
2. Then open it in Photoshop.
3. If you want click on the 'File > Save' in Photoshop.
4. Done :)

Comment: That works, but then there's no editing capabilities as far as layers, etc. I'm not sure if I would consider this exporting to PSD. More or less just saving it as a PNG and opening the PNG file from Photoshop, which is just opening an image. No layers for editing, etc. Am I missing something? I appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: I got you and edited my answer.